# Oracle APEX: Color the values in column of tabular form

Tags: javascript, css, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a `tabular form` where I want to display the value of column delta in different colors. **Delta is difference between column1 and column2**, which I am generating dynamically.

If the delta value is `>0` no change in color and if delta is `<0` the value should be in red color else green if value is `0`.

I am using oracle APEX VERSION : `4.2.1`

Comment: I can give you an example in javascript with css, could you post the column names?

Comment: Column name is `delta` where I need the color changes.

Comment: No, when I submit the page to save the values, the color of negative values in `DELTA` column should be in `red color`

Comment: There...I've updated the answer for the read only type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar problem hapened to me some time ago, what I did was:

First declare a css class

```
.cellColored{background-color:#ff0000 !important} 

/*notice the !important attribute, if not declared the browser will use the apex css definition*/
```

Then go to your tabular form definition -> Region Definition -> Attributes
In Static ID add and id like this:

```
tab_form_id
```

Then go to Report Atributes in your tabular form definition and edit the column you want to paint,in the field 'Element Attributes' add this: `class='classDelta'`

Then run a javascript function to asign the cellColored class to the table cells that fit the criteria, something like this:

```
function paintCells(){
    var tabForm = document.getElementById('tab_form_id');
    var cells = tabForm.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){  
        if((cells[i].headers === 'DELTA') && (Number(cells[i].getElementsByClassName('classDelta')[0].value) < 0)){
                            cells[i].className = cells[i].className + ' cellColored';
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `cells[i].headers === 'DELTA'` line, this should be the name of the column as defined in the report.

**EDIT**

The above was for input type elements, for read only columns you need to use this function:

```
function paintCells(){
    var tabForm = document.getElementById('tab_form_id');
    var cells = tabForm.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){  
        if((cells[i].headers === 'DELTA') && (Number(cells[i].innerHTML) < 0)){
                            cells[i].className = cells[i].className + ' cellColored';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried, but not changing in color of values  when value is ` < 0`

Comment: This worked for me, for obvious reasons you should run this after you calculate the delta values.

Comment: I placed the function in `Javascript` page component and CSS class  also in page component, but still value color not changing.
where I am doing wrong?

Comment: @MayhemMischief I don't know it can be a lot of things...how are you updating the values of delta?, also try opening the browser console to see if any error is being displayed.

Comment: I am updating value of delta dynamically using the `JavaScript`

Comment: @MayhemMischief you could post your code to show more clearly what you're doing.